# getting the file name of a page to apply class to nav jquery

Tags: jquery

The active class is not applied. 
This is what I have so far however it wont work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="list-group"> 
 <a href="page1.php"> page 1</a>
 <a href="page2.php"> page 2</a>
 <a href="page3.php"> page 3</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.active {
    color: red;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    alert(filename);

    $(".list-group a").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("href")==filename) // why cant i just add the var filename 
            $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: What does your html look like?  What exactly is "not working" and what do you want to have happen?

Comment: please explain what doesn't work, including any errors you are getting... it is unclear what exactly you are trying to ask...

Comment: The var filename is not being applied.

Comment: Applied how? You're checking if the filename and the href are **exactly** the same, and without seeing both the filename and the anchors, there's not much we can do ?

Comment: You modified your HTML in the update?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some needed brakcets -

```
if($(this).attr("href")==filename) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
}
```

But it works here (even if the brackets aren't present) - http://jsfiddle.net/MC54s/

Comment: Thank you so much Jay, I knew it was only something small.

Answer (score 0):

The selector you are using, `$(".list-group ul li a")` is not matching anything, because you do not have any unsorted lists that are children of `.list-group`

When you use a selector that is a space-separated list of element names, you are telling jQuery to start with selecting the first element listed, and then within that, to look for the next item, and then within *that* to look for the third item, etc.

Since you do not have any `ul` or `li` elements, the `a` element cannot be matched.

Try using this selector instead: `$('.list-group a')`

**--EDIT--**

Now that you've updated your question using the selector I suggested above, it should be working just fine.

Here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8W9vP/).

The only thing that's been changed is to use a text input to simulate the window location. Try typing `http://www.example.com/page2.php` into the text input. Notice that the link for page 2 now highlights in red as expected.